# Where does this usage "and you" as in titles come from?

Tags: etymology

So I'm noticing there are some occurrences of a fixed usage of “and you,” mainly in titles of articles introducing something new or important to reader.

It goes like “object inheritance, polymorphism, and you.”
The repeating occurrences make me think it has special origins. 
I Googled for a while but failed to figure out, because search results are full of explanations about “and you” as a trailing question or in other usages.

Is this a usage with sound origin, or just a common idiom?

Comment: I think it is just a well-used idiomatic form. A quick search revealed two magazines, *Animals and You* and *Fashion and You* which use it in their titles, as well as an information statement from the UK's Vehicle Licensing department, *Registration numbers and You*. I have no idea when it started but I, for one, cannot remember a time without it!

Comment: Undoubtedly the use of "and you" in titles originated with the TV show [Winky Dink and You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winky_Dink_and_You).

Comment: This is very doubtable. Science and You, 1939 or so, Chemistry and You, around the same time.

Comment: Being born in the early '90s, I think of it as an old-timey title convention that used to be used often, but is now used for a semi-humorous effect as an homage to those titles.

Answer (score 2):

[Winky Dink and You](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winky_Dink_and_You) was the first "interactive" TV show ever produced.  It was shown in the US in the mid-50, meaning that people who are now in their 60s and 70s watched it when they were elementary school age.  The meme "something something and you" was thus embedded in their psyches, and this generation was the one that in turn produced the books, games, toys -- and memes -- that have defined our current culture.

Answer (score -1):

> object inheritance, polymorphism, and you

A title like that simply means something like

> (this is an article about *the relationship between*) object inheritance, polymorphism, and you

Comment: I think the OP wants to know when that format first started to be used - a 19th century advertisement or classic book perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

"X and you" means "X as it relates to you"